# How do I remove the "dataframe" class with df.to_html?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have

```
df.to_html('table.html', classes='tablecss')
```

It will output a table:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe tablecss">
```

How do I make it only show "tablecss" and not "dataframe tablecss"?

Comment: i'm curious why you need to remove the dataframe class. does the dataframe class have specific formatting defined in your css?

Comment: Well this will be publicly visible online and I don't want to show that im using Python pandas to generate the data. My competition likes to steal whatever I do and the fewer clues I give them, the better.

Comment: `to_html()` returns a string, so I did `df.to_html('table.html', classes='tablecss').replace('class="dataframe ', 'class="')`

Answer (score 2):

Simplest fix (perhaps, there is a cleaner solution):

```
import re
html_updated = re.sub("class=\"dataframe ", "class=\"", df.head(5).to_html(classes='tablecss'))
with open("table.html", "w") as ouput_file:
    ouput_file.write(html_updated)
```